# C# SetSystemTime (WIN API) hooking

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, systemtime

I need restriction for time changes coming from different sources.
The best way, as i think, is to hook WINAPI function SetSystemTime (and maybe SetLocalTime).
I tried to hook this by using EasyHook library with injection in all running processes, owned by current system user. But it had no effect.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on my own system.
I use Windows 7 and when i changing time via standard clock setting dialog rundll.exe process runs and it starts dllhost.exe process which calls SetLocalTime.
I have tested it on another 2 PCs (WinXP & Win7) but there rundll.exe calls SetLocalTime itself.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you cannot just P/Invoke `SetSystemTime` as shown [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/SetSystemTime.html)?

Note that you need an elevated privilege to do this:

> An application must have system-time
>   privilege (the SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME
>   privilege) for this function to
>   succeed.

Comment: I dont want to call SetSystemTime, i want to hook it.